# Movable vertical line pine script

Tags: line, pine-script

I want to add a vertical line like below pic and it should be movable line, I'll tried many codes but they can't add movable vertical line, how can I do this ? please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the input.time function

```
inp_time1 = input.time(timestamp("21 Mar 2022 00:00 +0000"), "Date", confirm = true)
```

for example like this, the 'confirm' means you have you pick a time first before the indicator works.